# Grails oddness when trying to download a file from a URL

Tags: redirect, groovy, grails

I'm trying to automate firmware updates on some of my systems.  So, I first download a firmware file from the vendors website, and then I want to upload this to my TFTP server ready for my devices to pick up the new firmware.

I am using the following code to do this:-

```
def initiateUpdate(){
    if(!downloadFirmware()){
        println "Firmware download failed"
        return false
    }
}   

def downloadFirmware(){
    String downloadURL = 'https://myvendor.com/firmware/fw1.bin'
    redirect(url: downloadURL)
    return true  
    }
```

And this all works nicely, and I get a fw1.bin in my downloads directory.  But when I try to seamlessly upload it to my TFTP server, it's breaking the firmware download somehow. i.e. If I now add :-

```
def initiateUpdate(){
    if(!downloadFirmware()){
        println "Firmware download failed"
        return false
    }
    if(!uploadFirmware()){
        print "Firmware upload failed"
        return false
    }
}   

def downloadFirmware(){
    String downloadURL = 'https://myvendor.com/firmware/fw1.bin'
    redirect(url: downloadURL)
    return true  
    }

def uploadFirmware(){
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    def file=home + "\\Downloads\\fw1.bin"

    //  Now do the TFTP upload

    }
```

When I do the initiateUpdate, it doesn't download the file anymore, it arrives at the uploadFirmware section and fails as there is no file to upload.

I think I'm misunderstanding how the redirect works, so any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong, or a better way of doing it would be gratefully received.

Comment: Just to get things straight: those methods are inside a grails controller. you are running this grails app on your box and visit the initialUpdate function via your browser and you see the download in your browser?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Comment: Then I don't see how this is supposed to work. You can not do this in one step. You have to call `downloadFirmware` from your browser, then your browser downloads the file in your ~; next call `uploadFirmware` from your browser. If you want to do this in one go, you have to download the file _in the grails app_.  The redirect call there is nothing imperative - it just notes in the response to the browser, that the browser should be sent to another place.  Whenever the file is downloaded in your browser, is not known to the server.

Comment: Ah, right.     Ok, thanks I get that now.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use some some sort of http client to download the file from a remote location and save it on your server's disk. You can not do it with redirects inside the browser.

What I mean can look like so:

```
def uploadFirmware(){
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File file = new File( home, "\\Downloads\\fw1.bin" )
    String url = 'https://myvendor.com/firmware/fw1.bin'

    file.withOutputStream{ it << new URL( url ).inputStream() }

    true    
}
```

Comment: Thanks - yes I understand. I did come up with a solution using just that methodology, but it's a little less elegant than your solution.